# Reroute a DLL API call to another DLL in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll

So I have an application that calls a function from a dll,  but I want to intercept that call and map it to my custom dll. Refer to the image below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbSyK.png)

Comment: You can do it by using this library: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours Also there is one more simple to use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions

Comment: Will look into this thank you.

Comment: Please tell me if you succeeded to use any of them. First is detours from Microsoft and second is CPatcher. Both use very fine low level surgery of rewriting the machine code at runtime.